# How to force that specific div draggable could not be outside from parent div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a draggable vertical list to drag and drop rows using react.

I've created a div with a class name called placeholder, this specific div is used to create a space between other divs where it will drop.

My problem is that this specific div, 
how can it be draggable, can be dragged out of the div that contains it. And show me the next error because it's outside:

> NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

How can make that this specific div can not be outside from the div has been created??

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Item from '../Item';
import './list.scss';

let placeholder = document.createElement("div");
placeholder.className = "placeholder";

class DraggableVerticalList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props};
  }

  dragStart = (e) => {
    this.dragged = e.currentTarget;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.dragged);
  };

  dragEnd = (e) => {
    this.dragged.style.display = 'block';
    this.dragged.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
    // update state
    var data = this.state.colors;
    var from = Number(this.dragged.dataset.id);
    var to = Number(this.over.dataset.id);
    if(from < to) to--;
    data.splice(to, 0, data.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    this.setState({ colors: data });
  };

  dragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.dragged.style.display = "none";
    if(e.target.className === 'placeholder') return;
    this.over = e.target;
    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder, e.target);
  };

  render() {
        return (
            <div className="draggable-container" onDragOver={this.dragOver.bind(this)}>
        { this.state.colors.map((item, i) => {
          return ( 
            <div className="item" data-id={i} key={i} draggable='true' onDragEnd={this.dragEnd.bind(this)} onDragStart={this.dragStart.bind(this)}>
              <Item item={item} key={i} />
            </div>
          )})}
      </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DraggableVerticalList;
```

His css file:

```
.draggable-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: rgb(233, 201, 201);
    border-radius: 10px;

    .draggable-list {
        padding: 5px;
    }
}

.placeholder {
    background: rgb(255,240,120);
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    &:before {
        content: "Drop here";
        color: rgb(225,210,90);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
  dragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* With this line div cant be outside */
    if (e.target.className === 'draggable-container') return;

    this.dragged.style.display = "none";
    if(e.target.className === 'placeholder') return;
    this.over = e.target;
    e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder, e.target);
  };
```